# How is when an object moves gravity not effect it ? As Einstein sais?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity

**Experiment:**
*a water bottle with a hole . Water is falling from the hole when the bottle is in rest . When the bottle is released and falls , water stops falling as gravity is not doing effect on it . *
**But the bottle is falling because of effect of gravity how we can justify water is not falling because gravity has no effect on it **

Comment: Both water and the bottle fall with the same acceleration and so speed, so the water does not leave the bottle.

Comment: @trula That comment seems like it should be an answer.

Comment: That means when Earth is accelerating due to Sun's gravity people/objects moving with earth have no effect of sun's gravity?

Answer (score 1):

Both water and the bottle fall with the same acceleration and so speed, so the water does not leave the bottle.
To say there is no gravity exerted: put a scale under the bottle when it is standing you can read the weight, when its falling the scale says zero.